# Find most popular time to pick up bikes

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have a list of start times as varchar: `2021-02-03`  `4:48:00 AM`. I need to find the most popular start time. How would I do this?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Have you tried anything? It starts with couning rows per start time. Have you got this far? Show your query. Tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: On a side note: Why do you store timestamps as varchar? This is a bad idea, because thus you disable the validation and can store Februry 30 or the 80th day in the 13th month and the like. By not using the 24 hour format you add to this and even disable straight forward comparison and sorting. Don't do this. Always use the most appropriate data type.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't list your dbms (dbeaver can connect to any number of dbms types), so here's a postgres example.

First determine how to cast your string date as date and timestamp. In postgres, the `to_timestamp` function can achieve this. Using the `::time` is one method to then extract the time from the timestamp.

```
create table my_data (
  order_id integer, 
  order_date varchar(50)
  )
 ;
 
 insert into my_data values 
 (1, '2021-02-03 4:48:00 AM'), 
 (2, '2021-02-04 4:48:00 AM'), 
 (3, '2021-02-03 10:15:00 PM');
```

---

```
select to_timestamp(order_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS am,pm')::time as order_time, 
  count(order_id) as orders
from my_data
group by 1
order by 2 desc;
```

| order_time | orders |
| --- | --- |
| 04:48:00 | 2 |
| 22:15:00 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mWev3YGGhfjveAZkMrmBYk/0)